# Python - Find the sum of a Nested list

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having trouble of this recursive nested lists. The problem I have right now is the code work fine if the list isn't at the end of the list... I can't figure out what should I do to fix this.

```
def rsum(l):
    # Sum of all num in the list
    print l
    if isinstance(l[0], list):

        if len(l[0]) == 0:
            result = 0 + rsum(l[1:])

        else:
            sum_in_list = rsum(l[0])
            result = sum_in_list + rsum(l[1:])

    elif len(l) == 1:
        result = l[0]

    else:
        result = l[0] + rsum(l[1:])

    return result
```

So it work fine like this

```
l = [1, 2, [], 3, [2, 100], 4, [5], [], 2]
print rsum(l)
119
```

But if i do this

```
l = [1, 2, [], 3, [2, 100], 4, [5], [], [2]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help or suggestion to point me in the right direction would be great

Comment: Maybe it would be a better design to first check if `l` itself is a list, rather than if its first item is a list and then either act on it if it is (i.e. calculate the sum of its parts) or else just return its value if its an integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `l[0]` where there are no items in `l`, an `IndexError` will be raised.

Catch it like this -

```
else:
    try:
        result = l[0] + rsum(l[1:])
    except IndexError:
        result = 0
```

Or check for number of items in `l`

```
else:
    if len(l) > 0: 
        result = l[0] + rsum(l[1:])
    else: 
        result = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```
>>> flatten = lambda *n: (e for a in n
...     for e in (flatten(*a) if isinstance(a, (tuple, list)) else (a,)))
>>> l = [1, 2, [], 3, [2, 100], 4, [5], [], 2]
>>> sum(flatten(l))
119
```

In Python 3, you can recursively use `yield from` to flatten arbitrary lists:

```
def flatten(L):
    for item in L:
        try:
            yield from flatten(item)
        except TypeError:
            yield item

>>> l = [1, 2, [], 3, [2, 100], 4, [5], [], 2]
>>> sum(flatten(l))
119
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass it an empty list, it will try to access `l[0]` and cause the error.  But here's a simpler solution:

```
def rsum(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        return sum(rsum(v) for v in l)
    else:
        return l
```

This should handle all cases.

If you want a really concise version, you can use:

```
def rsum(l):
    return sum(map(rsum, l)) if isinstance(l, list) else l
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take

```
def rsum(L):
    return sum([rsum(i) for i in L]) if isinstance(L, list) else L
```